# CTOOLS/CSS 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: css, drupal, http-status-code-404, drupal-ctools

I'm experiencing a rather odd problem. My server log is full of calls to urls like:

```
/sites/default/files/ctools/css/588b003a48050c4e59cbeba2b453cb92.css
```

They are all 404 errors. But the site works perfectly well and looks good. Only I have a huge amount of 404 errors for pages CSS.

I've already cleaned the cache of the site entirely, but the problem persists.

I'm using Drupal 6.17.

It looks like the same issue as here:

[Optimize CSS files - file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516352/optimize-css-files-file-not-found)

But, I not have turned CSS optimization in Performance, and I'm using the module [Advance CSS/JS aggregation](http://drupal.org/project/advagg).

The problem started suddenly, the site is 2 years old and something like that has never happened to me.

Anyone who is experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Have you turned that other module off just to see if the errors are persisting? Maybe you could try turning it off, but turning the built-in Drupal CSS optimization on, and see what that does, as it doesn't rely on CTools.